# Get date/time with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android

folks!
I've got such date entry:

```
<pubDate>23/06/2011 11:57</pubDate>
```

I try to parse it:

```
mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
item_tag.getChild("pubDate").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String body) {
                date= new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
                try {
                    date=mDateFormat.parse(body);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

But I get something like that: `23/57/2011 11:57` **I get minutes instead of month value**
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK. Check out what do you really pass to this method, or just check what will happen if you insert line like:

```
body = "23/06/2011 11:57";
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in examples [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you should use '-' instead of '/' when instantiating a mask.